# Plugin properties are not added to FilePond object in React

Tags: reactjs, plugins, properties, filepond

I'm trying to set the `imagePreviewMaxHeight` from the `filepond-plugin-image-preview plugin` but it's not recognised. None of the properties on the preview plugin seems to exist on the FilePond object.

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { FilePond, registerPlugin } from 'react-filepond'
import FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation from 'filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation'
import FilePondPluginImagePreview from 'filepond-plugin-image-preview'
import 'filepond/dist/filepond.min.css'
import 'filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.css'

registerPlugin(FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation, FilePondPluginImagePreview)

const ImageUploaderPage = () => {
 /* Needed to add typ any below since prop files seems to use type FilePondFile but onupdatefiles
on the other hand accepts ActualFileObject and some other types but not FilePondFile. */
  const [files, setFiles] = useState<any[]>([])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Image Uploader</h1>
      <FilePond
        acceptedFileTypes={['image/png', 'image/jpeg']}
        files={files}
        onupdatefiles={setFiles}
        allowMultiple={true}
        imagePreviewMaxHeight={100}
        server="/api"
        labelIdle="Choose files or drag them here."
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default ImageUploaderPage
```

I am using TypeScript and I had some issues with that on other areas, adding that as a comment in case that could be an issue here as well.

The preview plugin is obviously registered since the selected images are shown... but when I access the FilePond object using oninit and a ref I can confirm that no plugin props are existing, only the default ones.

**EDIT: I found a property I can use that exists - `styleItemPanelAspectRatio` (It should be set to a string value of format 1 and not 1:1 like for example `stylePanelAspectRatio`**. So I'm happy for now... but the issue above still remain.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's an issue in the library with the typescript types not getting set properly.

**Solution:** Temporary fix is to add `// @ts-ignore` above the properties that are throwing errors. I.e. properties from the `FilePondPluginImagePreview` such as `imagePreviewHeight`.